# Removing option_for_select item with variable name in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code:

```
function remove_name(i) {
    var phase_name = document.getElementById('phase_rates_phase_name' + '-c' + i).value;
    $("select#payer_contract option[value='Phase 3']").remove();
}
```

This correctly removes the item from the dropdown if it is Phase 3, but I want to remove the variable. Is there a way of doing something like

```
$("select#payer_contract option[value='phase_name']").remove();
```

?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select#payer_contract option[value='" + phase_name + "']").remove();
```

Comment: This appears to remove all of the options in the option_for_select. Any idea why? It doesn't remove the specified name.

Comment: @JohnSmith It should work right, show your `options`, need more info